# receive() & fallback() not receiving funds sent via .send()

Tags: solidity, receive

I have this simple Caller Contract which is sending ether in 2 ways -

1. via .call() method // ether received in Called contract
2. via .send() method // ether not received in Called contract returns false in log

unfortunately I am unable to receive funds in Called contract, though it has receive() payable and fallback() payable available.
**My code for Caller Contract**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "./TestReceived.sol";

contract TestCaller {
    
    
    constructor()  payable {
        
    }
    
    function callme_recieved_test_1(TestReceived testReceived) public returns (bool ret) {
    
         ret  = payable(address(testReceived)).send(1 ether);
        
    }
    
   
    function callme_recieved_test_2(TestReceived testReceived) public returns (bool ret) {
    
        ( ret,)  = address(testReceived).call{value: 1 ether}("");
        
    }
    
    
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint balance) {
        
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    
}
```

**Code for The Called Contract**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract TestReceived {
 
    uint public rec_counter;

    event myevent(string );
    
    constructor() payable {
        
    }
    
    fallback()  payable external {
        emit myevent("no function found so this fallback function is called");
    }
    
    receive() payable external {
        
       rec_counter++;
       emit myevent("default received function is called");

    }
    
    
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint balance) {
        
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Kindly guide me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Enrique Alcazar Garzas help me boss

Comment: Are you using Remix IDE?